# Similarity between two text documents in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

You are provided with four documents, numbered 1 to 4, each with a single sentence of text. Determine the identifier of the document  which is the most similar to the first document, as computed according to the TF-IDF scores.

```
My name is Ankit,
Ankit name is very famous,
Ankit like his name
India has a lot of beautiful cities
```

Output the integer  (which may be either 2 or 3 or 4), leaving no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: what you have tried, show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

tfidf = vect.fit_transform(["My name is Ankit",
                             "Ankit name is very famous",
                             "Ankit like his name",
                             "India has a lot of beautiful cities"])

print ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)
```

Comment: How would you do this if you have two datasets [sentencesA, sentencesB], and get the cosine similarity between the two, but not all. Ex:   sent_list_a = ['i ate pizza', ' I fell down'] and sent_list_b = ['Im hungry', 'Im hurt]. For each row I would want to calculate the cosine similarity between sent_list_a and corresponding sent_list_b.